# Handle connection error events

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

How do I catch when my socket.io client cannot connect to the provided server?

This does not seem to work:

```
var socket = io('http://example.com:3000');

socket.on('connect_fail', function() {
    console.log("fail"); // doesn't get here
});
```

If my server is offline the event won't fire, and in the console it will repeat: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407852011369-40. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dashboard.inkstand.org' is therefore not allowed access.`

Everything works as expected when the server is **online**.

I can't find any good documentation on this, or any for client connection events.

Comment: Try a different port. I had the same problem and I think that's what I did (I had other problems, so it might've solved a different one, but give it a shot).

Comment: The port doesn't seem to be the problem. I can connect just fine when the server is running. I just want to have a way to know if the client fails to connect when the server is offline for whatever reason.

Comment: Oh, that error, it just means that the server is offline. I misunderstood your question, sorry. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I've found this is handled differently in v1.0.

```
var manager = io.Manager('http://example.com:3000', {});
var socket  = manager.socket('/');

manager.on('connect_error', function() {
    console.log("fail"); // does get here now
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
socket.on('connect_fail', function() {
    console.log("fail"); // doesn't get here
});
```

Try:

```
socket.on('error', function(err){
    console.log("fail");
    // Do stuff
});
```

This is fired when a connection fails (http://socket.io/docs/client-api/)